# Increment datetime by hour or min

Tags: shell-script, date

I'm working on a script that takes starting date and ending date as parameters. I need to increment start date by hour until it reach midnight and the date increment by one. Start date and end date may span multiple months. So, my idea is to take advantage of date function and I found so many posts covered that. However, I'm not getting correct results. For instance :

```
$ date -d "1999-05-20 23:00:00 +10 min"
Thu, May 20, 1999  9:01:00 AM

$ date -d "1999-05-20 00:00:00 +1 hour"
Wed, May 19, 1999  8:00:00 PM
```

As you can see, the returned values are all off. I'm not sure where am I doing wrong. I also would like to format the returned datetime as follows but without any success :

```
$ date -d "1998-12-31 23:00:00 +0.5 hour" +"%Y/%m/%d-%T"
date: invalid date ‘1998-12-31 23:00:00 +0.5 hour’
```

In case anyone is interested in my script pseudocode :

```
 While Start_date != End_Date :
    Do some stuff here
    Start_date = Start_date + 1 hour
```

Comment: Remove the `+` which makes it interpreted as a timezone offset

Comment: Thanks! Could you post it as reply so that I can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Stéphane Chazelas, the problem is caused by + sign before hour because it signals timezone instead of hour.

So instead of :

```
$ date -d "1999-05-20 00:00:00 +1 hour"
```

Use this :

```
$ date -d "1999-05-20 00:00:00 1 hour"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work on my Ubuntu 18.04 when prepending the delta:

```
date -d "-10min 1999-05-20 23:00:00"
Do 20. Mai 22:50:00 CEST 1999
```